No module named 'discord.commands'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Redacted\path\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from commands import setup_commands
  File "D:\Redacted\path\commands.py", line 4, in <module>
    from discord.commands import Option
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.commands'

Tried uninstalling all discord related libraries then just install discord.py but im still getting the same issue

We need to see your import statement to actually determine the problem

All in the documentation:

Old Discord commands
Interactions

In discord.py there are 2 types of commands:
If you are looking for the new Slash commands, they are in discord.app_commands:
from discord import app_commands

If you are looking for the old commands, you need to import discord.ext.commands:
from discord.ext import commands

Please refer to the docs to see how to use each one, and good luck!
